# Messages aggregation in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

For example I have next documents.

```
{sourceIP:1.1.1.1, destIP:2.2.2.2}
{sourceIP:1.1.1.1, destIP:3.3.3.3}
{sourceIP:1.1.1.1, destIP:4.4.4.4}
```

Is there anyway to automatically aggregate them into one document which will contain next data?

```
{sourceIP:1.1.1.1, destIP:{2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3,4.4.4.4}}
```

So it looks like group by in SQL, but generate new documents in elasticsearch instead of old one.

Comment: Do you want this to be automatically done by Elasticsearch? Or you want to do it in a query? How is Elasticsearch suppossed to know which documents to aggregate?

Comment: Check out bucket aggregations (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket.html)

Comment: dest IP can be an array and you can use upsert (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) while indexing

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is anyway to do indexing time auto-merging of documents.

However , it should be possible to acheive whatever result you are planning to query should be possible by using one of querying options offered by Elasticsearch - while indexing one document for ,

Like ..

- You can index seperate documents, query by sourceIP and use aggregations to give dest_ip
- Take count of documents if its just to find dest_ips for a source_ip

Also if you want to avoid duplicate source_id + dest_id combinations , you can concat  and use it as _id of document

Hope this helps.